# Where can I find a list of mutual zugzwangs from Queen vs Rook?

Tags: rook-endgame, queen-endgame, zugzwang

Is there a list of mzugs from KQKR?

Comment: Interesting tidbit: On a larger board (can't find it offhand, something like 16*16) there is indeed a mutual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular endgame, there are no mutual-zugzwang-positions.

An overview over the positions is at

http://chess.jaet.org/cgi-bin/mzugs

Comment: Thanks for the site, I found something else: http://chess.jaet.org/cgi-bin/dtx